# Play console verification Issue

Tags: google-play-console

Google couldn't verify your identity
I attempts many times for identity verification .
but it fails always.In my last attempts i uploaded driver license in proof of identity and also in proof of address. with exact name and address.
still it failed and right now i have not any option to upload document again in my console account.
so what should i do for next attempts and which document i should to upload ?

In my first attempt i uploaded pan card and adhar card which contains  owner name of trust .
It Fails then i uploded pan card and light bill, again it fails .
So in my last attempts i uploded driving license in proof of name and proof of address ,still it fails .
now i have not any option for upload document for complete my account verification.
so what should i do for new attempt?
and any help of google play developer ?

Comment: I'am facing a similar problem. Did you solve it? 
Was your proof of address accepted? 
Whenever I upload any document, it gets rejected with the message "Unsupported document type." They don't specify the exact issue, even though these documents are official from the government. What should we do in this situation?